# Can you define a function outside of @client.command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I started to code a discord bot (that takes your coffee order) for the first time yesterday, and can’t figure out how to define functions without placing them under @client.command or some similar line.

I have the code written in python but I need to be able to call different functions without making each one a separate command. (I don’t want to use on_message in this situation).

Is there a way to do this? Thanks to all who reply.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, could you show us your code and what you want an exchange with the bot to look like?  I think you're using the word "function" wrong, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Yes. I’m trying to implement the coffee bot project from Codecademy into discord.py. To do that, I need to switch around the syntax and define multiple functions. My question just got answered though: you can define functions just like you would in regular python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Define functions like normal functions and then you can call them.

```py
async def async_func():
    #code

def sync_func():
    #code

@client.command()
async def my_command(ctx):
    await async_func() #await is needed to call async functions
    sync_func() #call it normally
```